# Sorting list by alphabet if duplicate number exist

Tags: python, sorting

i would like to sort list or dict with 2 arguments.
first with **number** and If there was a duplicate number, it's then sort by **alphabet**.
Input:

```
a = {'A': 5, 'D': 6, 'B': 6, 'C':4}
```

What I Want:

```
[('C', 4), ('A', 5), ('B', 6), ('D', 6)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
sorted([*a.items()], key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]) )
```

Output:

```
[('C', 4), ('A', 5), ('B', 6), ('D', 6)]
```

Comment: I want to 'B' come before 'D'

Comment: this is output of your code:
[('C', 4), ('A', 5), ('D', 6), ('B', 6)]

Comment: I updated the code, which is now essentially the same with yatu’s.